# How fixed tag value for text field of custom cell in table view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield, uipickerview, custom-cell

I am implementing a tab;e in which i have created a custom cell for cell of tableview. On custom cell i am displaying two text field , one button and one image view. Now i want implement an event on text field. That is when i click on text field then appear picker view. With the help of picker view we can change text of text field. I have applied event like as when we click on text filed then appear a picker view. But when i scroll picker view then text field value not changing. so what i will do so that it happens? 
In table view i have 10 rows and i want to insert value from single picker view. I have also set tag on text field of custom cell by using this code.

> cell_object.txt_time.tag=[indexpath.row];

for selection value from picker view i use this code...

```
 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent: (NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView == myPicker)
    {
         if(cell_object.txt_time.tag==0)
           {
        [cell_object.txt_time setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array_time objectAtIndex: [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]]];
       }
      else if(cell_object.txt_time.tag==1)
           {
        [cell_object.txt_time setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array_time objectAtIndex: [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]]];
       }
    }
}
```

I have do for 10 rows text.tag. But it is not working.

What i do ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is cell_object? How would the pickerView delegate know what it is? If it the UITableView's Cell, then you need to create one again in your pickerView delegate above and the use viewWithTag to fetch them properly.

Comment: @Bourne cell_object is object of custom class.- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView == myPicker){
  if(cell_object.txt_time.tag==0)
  {
   cell_object= (Custom_cell2*)[table_routine cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
   [cell_object.txt_time setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array_time objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]]];
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple implementation would be:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent(NSInteger)component{
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[myArray objectAtIndex:row]];
    textfield.text = string;
}
```

myArray is the datasource for your UIPickerView. With the above code you will be able to tweak it to what you needed to do.